# "Type of expression is ambiguous without more context" error with GIDSignIn?

Tags: xcode, firebase, swiftui, google-signin

I have recently been building an app that utilises Google Sign-In through Google Firebase. I am having trouble fixing this error.

This is my code:

```
import SwiftUI
import Firebase
import GoogleSignIn
import FirebaseAuth

struct LoginView: View {
    @State private var email = ""
    @State private var password = ""
    @State private var isShowingRegistrationView = false
    @EnvironmentObject var contentVM: ContentViewModel
    var body: some View {
        ZStack{
            Image("background1")
                .resizable()
                .ignoresSafeArea()
            VStack{
                VStack{
                    Text("Log in")
                        .font(.system(size: 42, weight: .bold, design: .rounded))
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                    Text("to continue")
                        .font(.title3)
                        .foregroundColor(.white.opacity(0.7))
                }
                .padding(.vertical, 60)
                VStack{
                    TextField("Enter email", text: $email)
                        .textInputAutocapitalization(.never)
                        .disableAutocorrection(true)
                        .modifier(CustomTextField())
                    SecureField("Enter password", text: $password)
                        .textInputAutocapitalization(.never)
                        .disableAutocorrection(true)
                        .modifier(CustomTextField())
                }
                .padding(.horizontal)
                .padding(.top, 60)
                Spacer()
                VStack(spacing: 20){
                    Button{
                        Task{
                            await contentVM.signIn(withEmail: email, password: password)
                        }
                    } label: {
                        Text("Log in")
                    }
                    .buttonStyle(CustomButton())
                }
                HStack{
                    Text("Don't have an account?")
                        .font(.subheadline)
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                    Button {
                        isShowingRegistrationView = true
                    } label: {
                        Text("Sign up")
                            .font(.subheadline.bold())
                            .foregroundColor(.green.opacity(0.7))
                    }
                }
                Spacer()
                Text("or")
                    .font(.system(size: 25, weight: .bold, design: .rounded))
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .underline()
                GoogleSiginBtn {
                    guard let clientID = FirebaseApp.app()?.options.clientID else { return }
                    
                    let config = GIDConfiguration(clientID: clientID)
                    
                    //MARK: Error occurs here
                    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance.signIn(with: config, presenting: getRootViewController()) {  user, error in
                        
                        if let error = error {
                            //...
                            return
                        }
                        
                        guard
                            let authentication = user?.authentication,
                            let idToken = authentication.idToken
                        else {
                            return
                        }
                        
                        let credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(withIDToken: idToken,
                                                                       accessToken: authentication.accessToken)
                        // Use the credential to authenticate with Firebase
                        
                    }
                    
                } // GoogleSiginBtn
                Spacer()
            }
            .padding(.horizontal)
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $isShowingRegistrationView) {
            RegistrationView()
        }
    }
}
```

I am following this YouTube Tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M5LiqOBDeGg), but not entirely - rather, I am taking relevant code and putting it into an existing app. The video creator solves this issue at around 14:15 in the tutorial, in case you want to go through it.

Does anyone know how to solve this issue? I am relatively new to Firebase code and am afraid to try changing too many things in case I break the project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is the code that is generating the error `.signIn(with: config, presenting: ...` is no longer the correct syntax. Looks like some updates were made on the google side of things.

Try replacing the block of code within the `GoogleSiginBtn` with the following:

```
guard let clientID = FirebaseApp.app()?.options.clientID else { return }
        
let config = GIDConfiguration(clientID: clientID)

GIDSignIn.sharedInstance.configuration = config
        
GIDSignIn.sharedInstance.signIn(withPresenting: view.getRootViewController()) { signResult, error in
            
    if let error = error {
       //...
       return
    }
            
     guard let user = signResult?.user,
           let idToken = user.idToken else { return }
     
     let accessToken = user.accessToken
            
     let credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(withIDToken: idToken.tokenString, accessToken: accessToken.tokenString)

    // Use the credential to authenticate with Firebase

}
```